# How to extract specific array in Swift 4

Tags: ios, arrays, swift4.1

I want to get array value by it's key.

I set the array with below code inside looping .

```
let que = Question(questionText: "\(questionWord)", options: quizAnsArr, correctAns: correctArrIndex, wrongAns: -1, isAnswered: false)

        quizsArray += [que]
```

Now I get the below array. Here is my array.

```
[Kanji_Quiz.Question(questionText: "青", options: ["fast", "color", "heart", "blue"], correctAns: 3, wrongAns: -1, isAnswered: false), Kanji_Quiz.Question(questionText: "暑", options: ["owner", "heart", "hot (temperature)", "end"], correctAns: 2, wrongAns: -1, isAnswered: false)]
```

I was calling the value by using

```
print(quizsArray[questionText])
```

But it' show error. How can i call the value by index or smth. Please help me.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please explain a bit more what exactly you want to get from the array?

Comment: In clear method. I want to get the questionText from array and I want to get options by calling with index like this (options[0]).

I want  questionText to show in Label.

options[0] to show in Button 1 , options[1] to show in Button 2, options[2] to show in Button 3.

Comment: You can map `questionText`s from your array to another array and then loop through that array to show question texts on your `buttons`.

Answer (score 2):

@Kawazoe Kazuke

quizsArray is of type [Question]... right ?

So  By doing this: `print(quizsArray[questionText])`, you're asking your program to go into the `quizsArray: [Question]` and get the value where the index is equal to `questionText`.

I don't see how that should **NOT** *error*.

If you don't want to change quizsArray from a [Question] to a native Swift Dictionary ([String:Any]), Then here's what you need to do:

• loop over the quizsArray. Something like this should do the job:

```
    for question in quizsArray {
        <code>
    }
```

• only now will you have access to each question. so:

```
    for question in quizsArray {
        let text = question.getQuestionText()
        if text.elementsEqual('questionText') {
            let correctAnswerIndex = question.getQuestionAnswerIndex()
            print(question.getQuestionAnswer(correctAnswerIndex))
        }
    }
```

• Please note that the method `getQuestionAnswer(index: Int)` and `getQuestionAnswerIndex()` is just methods i made up. You have to go and code your "getters and setters" where you created the Question class/struct

• So in the end, you should convert all that code to a fucntion where the parameters will be the (key) questionText and the function returns the right answer or even the whole object for that matter. Then you'll be set

Comment: @Kawazoe Kazuke

I assumed that by : **I want to get array value by it's key.** , you wanted the correct answer for the given question. My apologies if that's not what you meant but comparing your code with your question, it makes very little sense to me .

Answer (score 0):

At the first you should find the index of questionText and then print that element:

```
if let index = quizsArray.index(of: questionText) {
    print(quizsArray[index])
}
```

But I suggest you to use Dictionary instead of array, you can achieve what you want in Dictionary easily.